# SQL Server : percentage calculation with new records as output

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below table as an output of a SQL query

```
ID  Car Type    Units Sold
---------------------------
1   Sedan       250
2   SUV         125
3   Total       375
```

I want a SQL query / procedure to produce below output

```
ID  Car Type    Units Sold
--------------------------
1   Sedan       250
2   SUV         125
3   Total       375
4   Sedan_Pct   66.67 (250/375)
5   SUV_Pct     33.33  (125/375)
```

Please note that `Car Type` will be increased in future and I want the percentage of each car type which should be appended to current table as '_Pct'.

Comment: It's not common to put aggregation results as rows inside your data table. It's better to put them as a column behind each record.

Comment: Is the total really part of your table?  It probably should not be, because it is just derived data.

Comment: @Code949 . . . Don't do it.  Don't add two new rows.  Simply add an additional column.

Comment: then how can you bifurgate the actual car type and percentage type

Answer (score 2):

Typically we might expect to see the percentages as a separate *column*, not as separate rows.  That being said, we can generate the output you want using grouping sets in SQL Server:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ID, CarType, SUM (UnitsSold) AS UnitsSold
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY 
        GROUPING SETS((ID, CarType), (CarType), ())
)

SELECT
    ID,
    COALECSE(CarType, 'Total') AS CarType,
    CASE WHEN ID IS NOT NULL OR CarType IS NULL
         THEN UnitsSold
         ELSE 100.0 * UnitsSold /
             SUM(CASE WHEN ID IS NOT NULL THEN UnitsSold END) OVER () END AS PctUnitsSold
FROM cte
ORDER BY
    ID DESC,
    CASE WHEN CarType IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 0 END,
    CarType;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: If I have more total records and their respective car types? like opentop, premium and a total record of(opentop + premium)

Comment: From what I tested, my answer should still work.  Did you test it?

Answer (score 0):

query for mysql server
use union  all in view or stored procedure -

```
declare @totalunitsold numeric(15,0);
set @totalunitsold =  (select unitsold from car where cartype='total')

select cartype,unitsold from car

union all

select cartype + '_pct', (unitsold/@totalunitsold) as pct from car
```

Comment: If I have more total records and I need to find the _pct for the respective cartypes then? Instead of a variable can i take a list?

Comment: is there anything  common in names of cartypes and their respective total field.

Comment: Yes, Two cars along with Total will be one set like Sedan_1, SUV_1, Total_1. And the next set will be Sedan_2,SUV_2 and Total_2. These all are car types ans as a whole there are 6 records in the table. I want precentage of each cartype divided by the repective total.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution will be using `Union`

```
SELECT CarType, UnitSold FROM Car
UNION
SELECT 'Total' CarType, SUM(UnitSold) UnitSold FROM Car
UNION
SELECT CarType + '_Pct' AS CarType, UnitSold / (SELECT SUM(UnitSold) FROM Car) * 100 AS UnitSold FROM Car
```

Might not be ideal in the long run

Answer (score 0):

this may help you

```
SELECT CarType+'_Pct', UnitSold/TotalSale*100 
FROM Car  cross join (select sum(UnitSold) TotalSale from Car) X
```

you can union that with your Table

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it!  Just add an additional column, not new rows:

```
select t.*,
       t.units_sold * 100.0 / sum(case when t.car_type = 'Total' then units_sold end) over () as ratio
from (<your query here>) t;
```

One fundamental reason why you want a different column is because `ratio` has a different type from `units_sold`.  Everything in a column (even in a result set) should be a similar attribute.